# Merge column with random values

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to generate some random values, but there is some problems which i don't know how to handle with. My SQL:

```
select * from 
(select round(dbms_random.value(1000000000,10000000000)) num from dual connect by rownum < X),
(Select round(dbms_random.value(1,5)) num1 from dual)
```

For now output looks:

```
1241511501  2
1515628080  2
1798442549  4
4061575813  2
5673495016  3
6582052088  5
7672299459  5
9360968960  5
9618384703  4
```

I would like to looks:

```
1241511501  5
    1515628080  5
    1798442549  5
    4061575813  5
    5673495016  5
    6582052088  5
    7672299459  5
    9360968960  5
    9618384703  5
```

Of course number "5" is optional, it should be also random number.

Comment: This looks like Oracle syntax rather than MySQL. Are you using Oracle or MySQL? If you are using Oracle please tag your question with the correct DBMS to ensure the answers given are relevant to you.

Comment: Yes right. My mistake. Of course that's Oracle syntax

Comment: Yes, first random value need to be between 10000000000 and 100000000 and the next one between 1 and 5.

Comment: do you want same number for all rows? i mean second column

Comment: Just like i showed on output. First column should be unique, second not but still random.

Comment: Then wat does tat make difference for you can you please be clear?..your result and expected are same

Comment: Honestly, I don't know understand what you wrote.. All what I want is Column1 with random number between 100000 and 1000000, and Column2 with NOT unique number. I need to use dbms_random becouse that code I'm going to use many time for inserting data into table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * from 
(select round(dbms_random.value(1000000000,10000000000)) num from dual connect by rownum < 10),
(Select round(dbms_random.value(1,5)) num1 from dual connect by rownum = 1)
```

Comment: Hello, It still doesn't work. I had to modify your SQL because i got an error ORA-00923,  SQL code looks: select round(dbms_random.value(1,5)),d1.* from 
(select round(dbms_random.value(1000000000,10000000000)) num from dual connect by rownum < 10) d1   , Still same situation :(

Comment: @maciek2791 I changed the answer, I'm not sure about the syntax but this is the idea.

Comment: Hmm It still doesn't work. Output: Column1 and Column2 return same values between 1-5.

Comment: @maciek2791 Changed it again, Now it should be ok. It was easier that I thought.

Comment: Yeeeea Right :) Works perfect. Thanks! :)